# Thinking sphinx not indexing belongs_to relationship properly in production but works fine in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I want to display the movies associated to a given author. On the author's page, I want users to be able to paginate, sort, and filter by keyword.

Everything works fine on my local machine. But, in production, the list of movies on the author's page is empty, and I can't figure out why. In production, in the console, I tested the following expressions, but no luck (always returns 0, while it returns values > 0 in dev):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :042 > Movie.search(:with => {:author_ids => [6]}).count
 => 0
 ruby-1.9.2-p290 :043 > Movie.search(:with => {:author_ids => 6}).count
 => 0
```

The weird thing is that I'm using a very similar code to display the movies associated to a topic on a topic's page, and it works great in development AND in production. For instance:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :051 > Movie.search(:with => {:topic_ids => 2}, :per_page   => 1000).count
 => 295
```

Here is how I define my Movie class:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :author
  has_many :topics
  ...

  define_index('movie') do
    ...
    has       author(:id),                :as         => :author_ids,
                                          :facet      => true

    has       topics(:id),                :as         => :topic_ids,
                                          :facet      => true

    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

And here is what my Author show controller looks like:

```
def show
    @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    keywords = params[:what] || ""
    with_params[:author_ids] = [@author.id]

    @movies = Movie.search(
            keywords,
        :with => with_params
    )

end
```

This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the Sphinx index in production, but I'm not sure how to investigate further to find the root of the problem...

**UPDATE:** Following Pat's suggestion, I updated Sphinx and everything was solved (I upgraded from 0.9.8 to 0.9.10)! I was confused because Sphinx is NOT a Gem (even though a Sphinx gem exists)... So I had to go through the regular download, make, make install process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with the obvious, but maybe this has already been tried - is the author_ids attribute something relatively new? Have you rebuilt (indexed *and* restarted) Sphinx since adding that attribute? `rake ts:rebuild` is the easy way to do that.

**Update**: It turns out updating Sphinx was the fix here - Alex can confirm which version, but I'm guessing 0.9.9 or better should do the trick.

Comment: Yes pat, this piece is taken care of. I rebuild my index on a regular basis.

Comment: yes... i'd would have loved it too! Anything suspicious about the way I defined the index? The way I call the search function (with an array containing the author id)?

Comment: Syntax looks fine. What value are we expecting? What's `Author.find(6).movies.count`?

Comment: In production AND in dev, I have `Author.find(6).movies.count` returning `25`, but `Movie.search(:with => {:author_ids => 6}, :per_page => 1000).count` returns `0` in prod, `25` in dev (I have the same data in both environments).

Comment: Pat, something caught my eye: 2 files in `db/sphinx/production/` in my app folder in production (namely `movie_core.spl` and `movie_delta.spl`) are owned by root, and my web-app user is not allowed to access them. I'm not sure what's in these files... Could it be linked to my problem?

Comment: hmmm... and something else: I have facets in my movie search results... all the facets work except for the one one Author.